Is it possible to develop such a browser plugin?
I would like to develop a plugin that recognises a specific person in photos (possibly also videos) and then manipulates the image. For example, Donald Trump gets a red clown nose whenever he appears in my browser (whether in Google image search, a newspaper article, a YouTube video, etc.).
Is it possible to develop such a plugin? And what does it take (time, knowledge, etc.)?
example

yes it is possible but it will slowdown browsing. Extension will have to go through each image in the loaded webpage, call some API with the images to convert them and then replace the images with results. Editing work better be done on server.
